# onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() not exactly after the window.load

Tags: javascript, android, iframe, youtube

How to trigger Youtube Player IFrame by user action and not immediately after the window load?

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

I want it this way because android seems buggy when IFrame is `display:none`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() function, and replace it with:

```
  function createPlayer(){
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });   
  }
```

Then make a button or similar that calls that function:

```
<button onclick="createPlayer()">Start</button>
```

Here is a working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yvufB/